# How can I set a specific SSD (lite) prediction architecture using a custom input resolution in TensorFlow ObjectDetection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-ssd

I would like to train a custom SSDLite-[MobileNetV2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04381.pdf) object detector on COCO dataset using [TensorFlow ObjectDetection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). Instead of fixed input resolution of (300,300), I'd like to have higher input resolution, e.g. VGA (640,480) or (544,544).
Since the architecture is fully convolutional, it is possible to have different input resolutions.
However, I would like to slightly change the SSD architecture in the following way:

Using the original input resolution of 300x300, we then have after the first 3x3 conv and 5 inverted bottlenecks a feature map of 19x19x96, after another two bottlenecks - 10x10x320, then by 1x1 - 10x10x1280, which then by using 3x3 depth-wise separable convolutions becomes 5x5x512, 3x3x256, 2x2x256, and 1x1x128.
The predictions are then made on the expanded version of 19x19 - 19x19x576, on 10x10x1280, and on all other feature maps with lower resolutions (5x5, 3x3, 2x2, 1x1) - 6 total.

If I have an input resolution of 554x554, then it's as follows:
after 3x3 conv and 5 inverted bottlenecks it's 34x34x96, after the another two - 17x17x320, but then in order to get to 1x1 resolution I need an extra layer:
9x9, 5x5, 3x3, 2x2, and then 1x1.

The way I want to modify the architecture is to skip over the 2x2 resolution and get from the 3x3 directly to 1x1 through an unpadded 3x3 depth-wise separable convolution. My question is whether this is possible using the TensorFlow ObjectDetection API without massive code modifications, e.g. by changing the [configuration file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config) or by slight code modifications.

EDIT: Added Python tag.

EDIT2 - try to make question more clear:
In the current architecture with current padding, in order to pass from feature map of 3x3 to 1x1 I need to go through feature map of 2x2 (3x3 conv, stride=2, padded). I would like to know if it's possible to change configuration in order to achieve going directly from 3x3 to 1x1 feature map with a single 3x3 conv, and if not - how to edit/make an alternative ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor (or other code) in order to achieve that.

Comment: Tensorflow is available in a bunch of languages. Please add appropriate tags for the language you use

Comment: Added Python tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the input resolution,change your .config file(get from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs).
Find this:
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
Chaneg the height and width value.
If you want to change the network architecture, it will be a little more difficult.The network architecture used by ssdlite_mobilenet_v2 is ssd_mobilenet_V2.The basic network is mobilenet v2 on slim/mobilenet/,write some custom code and defining your own model(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md).

Comment: rootkitchao, thanks for your comment. I know the things you mentioned, so I'll try to be a bit more specific about the question: in the current architecture with current padding, in order to pass from feature map of 3x3 to 1x1 I need to got through feature map of 2x2 (3x3 conv, stride=2, padded). I would like to know if it's possible to change configuration in order to achieve going directly from 3x3 to 1x1 feature map with a single 3x3 conv, and if not - how to edit/make an alternative ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor in order to achieve that. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to change the struct of the base net.See /slim/nets/mobilenet/.The mobilenet V2 is packaged in mobilenet_v2.py,see V2_DEF = dict() and mobilenet().And it called the mobilenet() func in moblienet.py.Its base unit is implemented in conv_block.py.I think you need to read the code and modify the base unit.